# Access cell data in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell

Seems like a really simple thing, but all of the research and everything I have tried just doesn't seem to work. I am using VS2013 and .Net 4.5

I have a 2 column WPF DataGrid that isn't using databinding. The grid is already populated with data from a SQLCE table and I want to select a row and return as a string the data in the cell of column 0 of the selected row.

I can see that the data is there in the debug watch window

I just don't know how to access that value so that I can use it.

> ```
>     private void dgPickList_MouseDoubleClick( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
>     {
>         selectItem();
>         this.Close();
>     }
>
>     private void selectItem()
>     {
>         _pickedItem = dgPickList.SelectedItem.ToString();
>     }
> ```

This code obviously doesn't work so well but it does let me see the cell data in a Non-Public members _values field.

I really appreciate any help.

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DataGrid.SelectedCells instead. This will return a collection of selected cells in which you can find the column you need to read.

eg:

```
var celldata=dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0];
var val=celldata.Column.GetCellContent(celldata.Item);
```

Comment: This really kicked my butt, but based on your info I was able to stumble onto something that worked. I am not exactly sure why the other ways didn't do the job. Using your example I was able to drill into the debug info and see the fields that I wanted but still couldn't extract them. Perhaps I am doing something odd (I don't know what) when I am setting up the DataGrid. I am reading the data into a DataTable. The code that I got working:             DbDataRecord id = ( DbDataRecord )dgPickList.SelectedItems[0];
            _pickedItem = Convert.ToString( id.GetValue( 0 ) );

Answer (score 1):

Cast the `SelectedItem` back to the original type you populated the grid with.

For example, if you use a `DataTable`, cast to a `DataRow` and grab the first column (here I'm assuming it's an integer type that represents a unique ID):

```
var id = ((DataRow)dgPickList.SelectedItem).Field<int>(0);
```

If you're using a collection of a custom class, something like this should work:

```
var id = ((MyClass)dgPickList.SelectedItem).Id;
```